# Find the exact location of an element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [-2,8,1], "C": [-451,23,326]})`

Is there any function that returns the exact location of an element? Assuming that the element exists in the table and no duplicate. E.g. if `element = 326` then it will return  `row:2 col:2`.
Many thanks

Comment: What if you have more that one 326, or none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` combined with `df.values`:

```
element = 326

indices = np.where(df.values == element)

row_index, col_index = indices[0][0], indices[1][0]

print("Row:", row_index)
print("Column:", col_index)
```

Output:

```
Row: 2
Column: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
element = 326

s = df.stack().eq(element)

out = s[s].index.tolist()
```

Output: `[(2, 'C')]`

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

# as positions
idx, col = np.where(df.eq(element))
# (array([2]), array([2]))

# as labels
df.index[idx], df.columns[col]
# (Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'), Index(['C'], dtype='object'))
```